# Node.js cannot access Google AdSense Management API. 'user does not have adsense account'

Tags: node.js, google-api-nodejs-client, adsense-api

I'm trying to generate AdSense reports on web app hosted on node.js.
Since it's a server-to-server communication i need to use service account. 
I followed [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#service-to-service-authentication) guide, but i always getting error:

```
{
 domain: "global"
 message: "User does not have an AdSense account."
 reason: "noAdSenseAccount"
}
```

also tried [this JSON Web Tokens Guide](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs#json-web-tokens) but also getting error above.

What i got:

- The Adsense Management API is enabled.
- Service account credentials are created
- Added service account email address to google AdSense User Management
- Tested in the Google API Explorer and it works just fine

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eiLD.png) 
**NOTE:** its status stuck on "pending". 
Here is the code i'm trying to connect and retrieve data with:

```
const googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');
const GOOGLE_KEYS = require(path.join(__dirname, '/credentials/jwt.keys.json'));

this.jwtClient = new googleAuth.JWT(
  GOOGLE_KEYS.client_email,
  null,
  GOOGLE_KEYS.private_key,
  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adsense'],
);
this.jwtClient.authorize(async (err: any, tokens: any) => {
  if (err) throw new Error(err);
  this.jwtClient.setCredentials(tokens);
  const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/adsense/v1.4/accounts`;
  const listData = await this.jwtClient.request({url})
    .catch((err: any) => {
      console.log(err, 'error');
      res.status(500).json(err)
     });
  res.status(200).json(data);
});
```

My questions is:

 1. Why is it stuck on "pending" status?

 2. Is there a way to acceess API using service account credentials?

 3. If yes which way i can achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AdSense API doesn't support Service Accounts[[1](https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/direct_requests#auth)], so you'll need to make OAuth credentials using the Web App flow[[2](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/web-app)].